# Programmatically start and stop certain IntegrationFlows in Spring Integration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I've created some IntegrationFlow's in spring integration like this:

```
IntegrationFlows.from(..).id("test").autoStartup(false). ..
```

How can I lookup this integration flow in Spring Integration and start it? I'm looking for something similar to `org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry` that can be used to start and stop `RabbitListener` instances.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the bean name of the flow

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow flow() {...}


...


@Autowired
public IntegrationFlow flow;

...

flow.stop();
```

(or `getBean("flow")` on the `ApplicationContext`).

Comment: Maybe this should read `StandardIntegrationFlow` instead of `IntegrationFlow` as `.stop()` is defined for the former and not the latter. Maybe the API changed since 2017, but this is the case for Spring Integration 5.x?

Comment: You are correct; or you can cast `IntegrationFlow` to `SmartLifecycle`. `IntegrationFlow` should probably extend `SmartLifecycle`. Please open a GitHub issue.

Comment: Done https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/3302